# DB Link Query Taking Too much time

Tags: sql, query-performance, dblink, enterprisedb

I have this query containing a dblink since I need to connect to another database and it seems so slow  Is there any way to make it fast?
In the other dblink query executing in Msec but once same query will be used in another server then its taking too much time to execute.
Index are already created in db link server. Is there any issue in the query.

Below query is used to fetch the latest invoices.

Below is the code:

```
WITH recursive derived AS
      (  SELECT inv_num, new_inv_num, 0 AS LEVEL
          FROM "CBF".cbf_inv_gen_trans@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 o ,
        "CBF".bill_master@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 bm
         WHERE  bm.invoice_no = o.new_inv_num
         AND BM.id::number = o.batch_id::number 
         AND  o.inv_num = '061810G10024409'
           AND o.new_inv_num NOT LIKE '%XX%'
           AND o.new_inv_num IS NOT NULL
           AND o.attribute_id IS NOT NULL
           AND o.attr_val IS NOT NULL
           AND bm.bill_date is not null
           UNION
               SELECT distinct o.inv_num, cr.new_inv_num, 0 AS LEVEL
          FROM "CBF".cbf_inv_gen_trans@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 o , "CBF".cbf_inv_gen_trans@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 CR, 
          "CBF".bill_master@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 bm
         WHERE  o.new_inv_num = cr.inv_num
         and bm.invoice_no = cr.new_inv_num
          AND BM.id::number = cr.batch_id::number
        AND o.inv_num = '061810G10024409'
        and o.new_inv_num ilike '%XX%'
        AND o.attribute_id IS NOT NULL
        and cr.new_inv_num not  ilike '%XX%'
        and cr.attribute_id ='38'
        AND bm.bill_date is not null
        UNION
          select ad.invoice_no,ad.new_inv_num, 0 AS LEVEL
            from "CBF".cbf_custom_attr_value_details@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 ad ,"CBF".bill_master@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 bm
        WHERE bm.invoice_no = ad.new_inv_num
         AND BM.id::number = ad.batch_id::number 
         AND attribute_id = 129 and 
             new_inv_num is not null 
             and new_inv_num not like '%XX%'
             and ad.invoice_no = '061810G10024409'
              AND bm.bill_date is not null
             ), MERGE as (
             SELECT * 
            FROM derived
            union all
                SELECT e.inv_num, e.new_inv_num, LEVEL + 1
                  FROM "CBF".cbf_inv_gen_trans@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 e
                 inner join MERGE s ON s.new_inv_num = e.inv_num
                 inner JOIN "CBF".BILL_MASTER@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 bm 
                 ON BM.INVOICE_NO = e.NEW_INV_NUM  and BM.id::number = e.batch_id::number 
                 WHERE e.new_inv_num NOT LIKE '%XX%'
                   AND e.new_inv_num IS NOT NULL
                   AND e.attribute_id IS NOT NULL
                   AND e.attr_val IS NOT NULL
                   AND BM.BILL_DATE IS NOT NULL
                ),
        RECREATE AS (***
                 SELECT * 
            FROM derived
            union all
            select ad.invoice_no,ad.new_inv_num,LEVEL + 1
                    from "CBF".cbf_custom_attr_value_details@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 ad
                     inner join RECREATE s ON s.new_inv_num = ad.invoice_no
                     inner JOIN "CBF".BILL_MASTER@prod_lbt_temp_cluster123 bm ON
                      BM.INVOICE_NO = ad.NEW_INV_NUM  and BM.id::number = ad.batch_id::number 
                     where attribute_id = 129  
                     AND ad.new_inv_num is not null 
                     and ad.new_inv_num not like '%XX%'
                     AND BM.BILL_DATE IS NOT NULL
                )
       Select new_inv_num INTO  v_new_inv_num from (SELECT * from MERGE 
          union
          select * from RECREATE
    )
           WHERE LEVEL  in (select MAX(LVL) from (
                SELECT max(LEVEL) LVL FROM MERGE
                UNION 
                SELECT max(LEVEL) LVL FROM RECREATE
                UNION 
                SELECT max(LEVEL) LVL FROM derived )
            ) limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanx for the comment... But for sure this is query is working in mesc in postgress db but same query is taking time from another postgress server..

Comment: What do you get when you run `select version();`

Comment: "EnterpriseDB 10.1.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18), 64-bit"